# cursorInfo command not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cursor

I assigned a cursor to a variable like so in MongoDB:

```
var myCursor = db.inventory.find({},{'name':1}).sort({'name':1});
```

Where `name` is an attribute of the collection `inventory`. It may help to know that my `inventory` collection only has 4 documents.

I then used the `cursorInfo`command using the following code:

```
db.runCommand({cursorInfo:1});
```

When I see the output though, it claims that the `totalOpen` cursors are 0, that the `clientCursors_size` of the cursors are 0, and that the number of `timedOut` cursors is also 0. Is there any specific reason why the `cursorInfo` cannot detect `myCursor`? (I'm sorry if this is a beginner's question, but I just started learning MongoDB.)

Note: I also tried to use the cursor completely (through `myCursor`) and retrieve one item in the cursor (through `myCursor[0]`), yet I still got the same output.

Comment: Probably because the cursor in the console is eager, this means by the time you come to query the cursor has already gced itself since it has finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include a batchSize() for that if you have very less no of documents in the collection : db.items.find().batchSize(2) for that

Go through this link to know the cursor behavior : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#cursor-behaviors

Since you are using sort, and I am sure either their is no index on 'name' key or there are no more than 101 documents ( or 1 MB of documents ). Let me explain using one example.

```
test:Mongo > db.runCommand({cursorInfo:1});
{ "totalOpen" : 2, "clientCursors_size" : 2, "timedOut" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
test:Mongo > var x = db.test2.find().sort({ a : -1}).batchSize(5);
test:Mongo > x.next()
test:Mongo > db.runCommand({cursorInfo:1});
{ "totalOpen" : 2, "clientCursors_size" : 2, "timedOut" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
```

So, there is no change in the open cursors ( check the doc I pasted above ), because of missing index on { a : 1 }
Now lets add the index.

```
test:Mongo > db.test2.ensureIndex({ a : -1 })
test:Mongo > var x = db.test2.find().sort({ a : -1}).batchSize(5);
test:Mongo > db.runCommand({cursorInfo:1});
{ "totalOpen" : 2, "clientCursors_size" : 2, "timedOut" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
test:Mongo > x.next()
test:Mongo > db.runCommand({cursorInfo:1});
{ "totalOpen" : 3, "clientCursors_size" : 3, "timedOut" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
```